# Integrated Video Card

Tags: video, graphics-card

Looked through many different questions throughout the site already and I haven't quite found an explanation at this time yet.  Looked through multiple websites as well, maybe it's just something that I'm missing.

Recently got a GeForce 210 1GB Silent video card, was just looking for a slight display increase.  The system has 4GB of ram.

I checked out the graphics via dxdiag and the integrated ramdac shows near 3GB at 2796MB.

If I have only a 1GB card why would his be reflected?

Answer (score 0):

`dxdiag` is showing this because that is the amount of your *system* memory that is able to be *shared* between the graphics card and CPU.

It is nothing to do with the amount of onboard memory on the graphics card or your amount of system ram but is instead effectively the amount of memory that can be used to buffer textures and data before it gets sent over to the graphics card.

[The internet](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=dxdiag+shared+memory) has much to say on this issue:

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001308.htm
http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/323772-33-dxdiag-approx-total-memory
http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1338659-Graphics-card-question-I-bough-2gb-says-I-have-4gb